# BlackBerry - Uncaught exception: Application is not responding; process terminated

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an application using the Blackberry plugin for eclipse and I am getting the following error when making a call to a web service when I have deployed my application to a production server and handset... it works in my local simulator and development environment. (I can't hook my simulator directly to my production environment)

> Uncaught exception: Application
>   app(150) is not responding; process
>   terminated

The call is being made from another thread.

The thread is passed to my CustomThreadManager to run

```
ClientChangeThread thread = new ClientChangeThread();
CustomThreadManager.Start(thread, true);
```

CustomThreadManager

```
ProgressPopup _progress = null; 
    if(showProgress){
        _progress = new ProgressPopup("Loading...");
        _progress.Open();
    }
    thread.start();             

    while (thread.isRunning())
    {
        try
        {
            CustomThread.sleep(300);
            if(showProgress){
                _progress.doPaint();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Dialog.alert("Error contacting webservice\n" + e.getMessage());
            Functions.moveBack();
        }                   
    }
    if(showProgress)
        _progress.Close();
```

Some calls work while others dont.
The web service returns results fairly quickly so Im not sure if its the web service is too slow or problems with the threading.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Thread](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/lang/Thread.html).sleep() does not release any locks.  This means your code to update the progress bar in the while-loop is holding the UI event lock, and prevents other UI updates from happening until the while loop terminates -- in this case when thread.isRunning() returns false.

You can use `UiApplication.invokeLater(Runnable, long, boolean)` to schedule a repeating UI update that will only hold the event lock while the Runnable is executing.