# BlackBerry downloading a file

Tags: file, blackberry, download, inputstream, outputstream

I have a blackberry application that is downloading a file from online. Sometimes the download succeeds and other times it fails somewhere in the middle. It only seems to be a problem on the Curve 9360 device. When it fails, on the device it closes my app and shows a pop-up that says

> "Uncaught exeption Application [MyApp] is not responding; process
>   terminated"

this is the while loop that it is in when it fails:

```
 byte data[] = new byte[1024];

         try {
            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                 total += count;
                 progress = (int)(total*100/lengthOfWebFile);
                 if(model.getValue() < progress){
                     UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
                     {
                         public void run()
                         {
                             EmbeddedMediaScreen.this.model.setValue(progress);
                         }
                     });
                 }
                 //write this chunk
                 os.write(data, 0, count);              
             }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't get any kind of stack trace in the console when this happens. I get the following:

```
[710.328] Application BBCurve9360DemoLoop(314) is not responding; process terminated
[710.328] 
[710.429] [0 0]
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
.[lots more "0 2"s]
.
.
.
[710.429] 2 203
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
[710.429] 0 2
.[lots more "0 2"s
.
.
```

Has anyone run across anything like this while pro grammatically downloading a file on a blackberry device?

Can anyone see anything in my IO loop that would cause this type of crash?

And lastly does anyone know if there is someway that I can get an actual stack trace of whatever exception is being thrown?

Comment: Check the eventlog to see if there is something relevant to your app there. alt+LGLG

Comment: checked inside there and found something referencing my app. when select it the only info given is name, severity, guid, timestamp and "AMFD [myAppname](323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Thread.yield()` after `os.write()`. This will give other threads the opportunity to run, and should stop your app from being killed by the JVM.

Comment: Is the amount of time that I have it sleep for important? I set it up with sleep(100) like you suggested but this leads to the download taking a very long time since it is sleeping 1/10 of a second for every 1024 bytes in the file. If I set it to something lower like 10, or 5 will it have the same effect in preventing the jvm from killing me?

Comment: I've gone with Thread.sleep(10); and it seems to be working so far [*knocks on his wooden desk*] If I get through a bit more testing and all is well I'll accept your answer. And thanks a TON for helping me out.

Comment: No problem Tim, the time specified in sleep is not important as long as you DO sleep for some time to give other threads the chance to execute.

Comment: Actually `Thread.yield()` might work better than `Thread.sleep(10)` and is more semantically correct, answer updated.

Comment: Perfect, using yield allows my download to complete at essentially the same speed, and prevents my app from being killed by the JVM. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To print stack trace, you have to catch throwable instead of exception. My conclusion is based on the RIM note given below

> RIM Implementation Note
>   Only uncaught exceptions have stack traces. The VM checks the current catch stack and if it finds anything that will catch the exception, it eliminates the stack trace to save time and memory. Any code in the current stack such as catch (Exception e) eliminates the stack trace.
>   If the exception is never caught, then the stack trace is generated.The stack trace is also generated if there is code such as catch (Throwable t).

Also

You get a "process terminated" message if the while loop doesnt end and the loop is continually putting in runnable objects in the event thread. Try to get rid of the invokeLater() and see if your process still gets terminated.

Comment: Testing it this way now. If I get rid of the invokeLater() how can I update the progress bar that is on the screen since my downloading is happening in a different thread?

Comment: this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376140/blackberry-uncaught-exception-application-is-not-responding-process-terminat

Comment: Yes of course without invokelater() you cannot update event thread. I suggested removing it for some time so we know without it if the app works ok. You should use UiApplication.invokeLater(Runnable, long, boolean)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for helping me out. I've started using the recurring invoke later that you pointed me to.